# Magento Observer throwing Error

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I am using `Sales_order_place_before` event in my module. And the observer returns the error,

```
User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 3937"
```

#### config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Observersample_Event>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Observersample_Event>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Observersample_Event>
                <class>Observersample_Event_Model</class>
            </Observersample_Event>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_before>
                <observers>
                    <observersample_event_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Observersample_Event_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>example</method>
                    </observersample_event_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

#### Observer.php:

```
class Observersample_Event_Model_Observer{

    public function example($observer){
        Mage::log("Order is Placed");
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $shipping = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $customer = $order->getCustomer();
        Mage::log($billing->getData());
        Mage::log($order->getData());
    }
}
```

#### systems.log:

```
2015-06-12T06:36:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): Order is Placed
2015-06-12T06:36:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
)
2015-06-12T06:34:45+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 3937
```

I hope someone will help me on this issue.

Comment: I can't explain exactly why, but I did have the same problem, just comment out the Mage::log part and I think you should be fine

Comment: ok i will check @lloiacono...

Comment: that error message is shown when you run some queries in the transaction and you don't commit the transaction. So something is stopping the order save process.

Comment: But i have checked the order table,the order is placed...@Marius

Comment: reomove log print  and check

Comment: i removed log and i just given the var_dump($order); die();...but its not working

Comment: i removed log and i just given the var_dump($order); die();...but its not working @lloiacono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `Mage::log($billing->getData());` This is not the correct format.. So changing this like,

```
Mage::log(var_export($billing->debug(), TRUE));
```

gives output.

Observer.php:

```
class Observersample_Event_Model_Observer{

    public function example($observer){
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $shipping = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $customer = $order->getCustomer();
        Mage::log(var_export($order->debug(), TRUE), null,'order.log');
        Mage::log(var_export($billing->debug(),TRUE),null,'billing.log');
    }
}
```

for details check this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/debug